# Get campaign metrics brokedowm by day

Tags: python, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to get ads campaign metrics for a period of time, let's say for the last 30 days.  This gives me aggregated for adset and platform.

```
params = {
        'date_preset':  'last_30d', 
        'breakdowns': ['publisher_platform'],
        'level': 'adset',
        'fields': fields }
```

If I use `{'time_increment': 1}` parameter, it just gives data of first day of set period and thats it. 2 or higher just not work as I need daily performance numbers.
If I iterate through date range I get

```
ERROR:root:(#17) User request limit reached
```

Any tips on how to solve it?

Comment: Would you please **clarify** your question and also what you've tried?

Comment: Retrieve facebook campaigns data, what campaign had how many clicks, impressions and so on. In FB report manager it gives option to get these numbers brokedown by day, but API doesnt have such a parameter.

I tried  date presets and time_increment parameter, also date ranges and iterating through through range.